# Wait until condition is met

Tags: python, multithreading

I am pretty new to Python. I have some code using `Thread` which should stop until a condition is met.

When I press key `1` in the console the script just stops instead of running the part under the condition `test1 == 1:`.

When the condition is met, I want to run the script **only 1 time per Thread with the existing sessions**.

---

Code:

```
  def test()

    #some code  
    test1 = 0

    while (test1 == 1): #Wait until is set 1 in if __name__ == '__main__': and run the code only 1 time 
        response = session.get('https://www.example.com/')


        opts = ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)

        driver.get(response.url + '#/checkout/login')
        print "Checking Out..."
        test1+=1

def Main():
        t1 = Thread(target=test, args=())
        t1.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = input('How many tasks you want to start? \n')
    for i in range(test):
        Main()
    test1 = input('Proceed? if yes press 1 \n')
```

Comment: `test1 = 0 ... while (test1 == 1):`, the loop will never run because `test1` isn't equal to 1

Comment: `while` doesn't mean `wait`

Comment: At the last line of the script you can see, that I set test1 = 1, so the loop should run then

Comment: You never get to `test1 +=1` since you never enter the loop to begin with.

Comment: You seem to expect `while(p):` to loop *until* the condition is true. That is exactly backwards. If you want a loop to run until the condition is true you want it to run while it is *false*. Thus you seem to expect `while(p)` to behave like `while(not p)`. In your case, you seem to actually want `while(test1 != 1):`

Answer (score 0):

If you want run your code only once, then why you are going with looping.
Just simply specify your code without loops.

```
response = session.get('https://www.example.com/')
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.get(response.url + '#/checkout/login')
print "Checking Out..."
test1+=1
```

Or else you can specify your while statement something like.

```
While True:
    // Logic
    break # once logic finely executed, then break the loop
```

While loops will executes the given block of statements until the condition will become False. In your case, while condition is always False, so at initial control stage itself the while block will be skipped.

Comment: Yes, but when I run the code without loops, then it just runs without any conditions. I want it to run after it asks me like "You would proceed?" and I type in a value, and when the loop mets the condition, then the code should run one time per thread with the existing session

Answer (score 0):

```
  checker = 0
  placeHolder = 0


   def Main():
       global test
       global checker
       global placeHolder

       if checker == 0:
         t1 = Thread(target=test, args=())
         t1.start()

       while placeHolder <= test:            

         response = session.get('https://www.example.com/')


         opts = ChromeOptions()
         opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
         driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)

         driver.get(response.url + '#/checkout/login')
         print "Checking Out..."

         placeHolder +=1






if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = input('How many tasks you want to start? \n')
    Main()
```

Comment: I mean one time per thread. When i have like 7 threads, it should run 7 times. This code runs one time in generally then.

Comment: hmm let me see.

Comment: tell me about it when you have tested it.Its also like a while loop :) but faster

Comment: There is some error in it: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'placeHolder' referenced before assignment.    And what about the session? It should continue the session of each Thread then, and not start a new session for each thread. Well it keep the session?

Comment: in the main function at the top i have made placeHolder "h" lowercase instead of uppercase

Comment: Yeah it works now, but the session won´t proceed of the threads, it starts a new session with new cookies. I need to continue the sessions of each threads, you know how to do this?

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: Appreciate it!  You have like Skype or something? Then I could send you the whole script, I think it's easier to understand then, what I want. My Skype: denni.1802

Comment: burhanasif59@gmail.com and yeah I will have to work on it and hour or two

Comment: when you have sent it tell me here

Comment: are you sending it?

Comment: Yeah, one moment please

Comment: I sent it to your email, appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, it is python 2.7, would be nice when you can send per mail back then instead of posting here